# Find two table where one table has redundant value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
user_list
+---------------------+
+  user_id  +  name   +
+---------------------+
+ 001       + Anna    +
+---------------------+
+ 004       + David   +
+----------------------
...


job_list
+---------------------+
+  user_id  +  job    +
+---------------------+
+ 001       + Norse   +
+---------------------+
+ 002       + Doctor  +
+---------------------+
+ 003       + Sales   +
+----------------------
+ 004       + Driver  +
+----------------------
...
```

I want to find the records which `job_list` exists but `user_list` doesn't exists

For example, some user may deleted for some reason

but their record still stay in the database, so I want to find them and remove

In this case, the returning result should be 002 and 003

```
SELECT * FROM `user_list` ul, `job_list` jl WHERE jl.user_id NOT LIKE ul.user_id;
```

I tried the SQL command above but not work, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM job_list AS jl
LEFT JOIN user_list AS ul ON ul.user_id = jl.user_id
WHERE ul.user_id IS NULL
```

should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `job_list` jl 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_list ul WHERE ul.user_id=jl.user_Id)
```

Comment: No problem @nasaorc. Using `NOT EXISTS` is very efficent as you dont have to `JOIN` entire tables, merley checking records you want to discard. Sometimes however, using `WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT...)` can be more efficent. Depending on the size of the database and index etc.

Comment: More important is the DBMS and mySQL is well-known for its crappy subquery implemention :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care abaut know what records remove and you just whant to remove them something like this should do the trick: (warning: subquery´s are extremly inefficient)

```
delete from job_list where user_id not in ( select user_id from user_list)
```

if you whant to know the records before remove them you shuld join the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM job_list
    LEFT JOIN user_list 
    ON user_list .user_id = job_list.user_id
    WHERE user_list.user_id = NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT user_id FROM job_list MINUS SELECT user_id FROM user_list;
```